# Optimize this SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a SQL query within a foreach loop. Sometimes there can be many, and I mean a lot of queries to do, depending on several criteria, up to 78 queries potentially.

Now, I know that premature optimisation is root cause of all evil, but I don't want to see 78 queries - it's just not healthy.

Here's the code:

```
$crumbs = explode(",", $user['data']['depts']);

foreach ($crumbs as &$value) {
    $data = $db->query("SELECT id FROM tbl_depts WHERE id = '" . $value . "'");
    $crumb = $data->fetch_assoc();
    $dsn = $db->query("SELECT msg, datetime FROM tbl_motd WHERE deptid = '" . $value . "'");
    $motd = $dsn->fetch_assoc();
    if ($motd['msg'] != "") {
        <?php echo $motd['msg']; ?>
    }
}
```

Can I make it any better?

Comment: Aside from the optimizations below, you might want to consider making it a stored procedure instead of a straight select to improve performance.

Comment: be aware that this code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Hello Daniel, why is this the case? The data is only getting an array, which would have been sanitised before putting in. Aldo, $user['data'] and its children are also sanitised before this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`IN MySQL operator`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) to search over a set of values for `id`:

```
$ids = '"' . implode('", "',$crumbs) . '"';
$query1 = "SELECT id FROM tbl_depts WHERE id IN (" . $ids . ")";
$query2 = "SELECT msg, datetime FROM tbl_motd WHERE deptid IN (" . $ids . ")";
```

And so you will not need to retrieve all data you need using `foreach` loop, so you will have only 2 queries instead of 78.

Example: I have a table named `table` with 10 records which ids are: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 (auto-incremented). I know I need records with ids 1,5,8. My query will be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id in (1,5,8);";
```

And I don't understand why do you need to use `&` operator in `foreach` loop if you don't modify the `$crubms` arrays values.

Comment: So I would replace the two queries above with this, but rewrite the code itself?

Comment: It's just habit that I put & operator in.

Comment: @Shamil, Yes. You will have to rewrite the code since it uses another approach.

Comment: @Shamil it's a bad habit then. You might occasionally modify any array in your program and it will be hard to find out where an error is hidden.

Comment: Using the & operator will make the program run slightly faster as the program doesn't need to allocate memory to store each $value in.

Comment: be aware that this code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is want you want.

```
SELECT msg, datetime
FROM tbl_depts td
INNER JOIN tbl_motd tm ON td.id = tm.deptid
```

Comment: which one should I replace it with?

Comment: I did not really looked into the logic of queries, but I think you've forgotten `WHERE` somewhere. I think OPs query result is restricted by a set of particular ids. Should be  `INNER JOIN tbl_motd tm ON td.id = tm.deptid WHERE td.id in (<set of ids>)`, probably?